# Is slice() not the same as :gt:lt?

Tags: jquery

I'm a little bit curious about this. I thought `slice()` was pretty much the same as `:gt:lt` but here is an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chanckjh/u8d5qv93/1/)

As you can see the green background does not apply to `.nr4`. Why is that and when do you use `slice()` correctly instead of `:gt:lt`?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nr1 li').slice(2, 5).css('background', 'red');
    $('.nr2 li:gt(1):lt(3)').css('background', 'blue');
    //$('ul:gt(1)').find('li:gt(2)').css('background', 'purple');

    $('ul').slice(2, 4).find('li:lt(2)').css('background', 'yellow'); // .nr3 and .nr4 has a yellow background
    $('ul').slice(2, 4).find('li').slice(4, 6).css('background', 'green'); // .nr3 has green background but .nr4 does not
});
```

Comment: `.slice([starting 0 based index, inclusive],[ending 0 based index, exclusive])` so  `[0,1,2,3,4].slice(1,3)` returns `[1,2]` because index 1 is 1 and index 3 is 3 but it's not included. IOW the start is the equiv of `>=` or `:gte` if there were such a thing as `:gte` (greater than or equals). But `:gt` is equiv of `>` not `>=`. So you can do `.slice(start+1,end)` for the equiv of `:gl(start):lt(end)`

Answer (score 0):

The `.find`  is executed on a previous result (`$('ul').slice(2, 4)`) and analyzes each element inside that result with its criteria (descendants of the selection context), starting a new index count for each element.

`.find('li:lt(2)')` :

```
ul2 (li1 li2 li3 li4 li5 li6)
ul2 (li1 li2 li3 li4 li5 li6)
```

whereas `.find('li')` first returns a result of all 12 items

```
li1 li2 li3 li4 li5 li6
li7 li8 li9 li10 li11 li12
```

and the `.slice(4, 6)` is performed on that total collection, thus returning the last 3 items of the first row (or 3rd row in your example)

If you would use `.slice(6, 8)`, you'd see that the first 2 blocks of the last row would be coloured green.

Another example: with `$('ul').find('li:first').css('background', 'yellow');` The first block of each row would be coloured.
But with `$('ul li:first').css('background', 'yellow');` only the first row's block would be coloured, because the indices would be determined on the total of all `li`s

Note: these are only observations, can't really find a good reference that this is the intended behaviour, I'm only assuming it is.